# quaternion algebra: possible error on proof

Tags: quaternions

I am reading this proof and I don't understand whether the highlighted term in second and third step is a typo or I am missing something. I would expect it to be

$$qpq^*$$

[image: e]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the next line, where it says "by bilinearity", it certainly seems that it's being used as if it were $qpq^*$.

Comment: That is what I thought as well indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it should be $qpq^* + (qpq^*)^*$.

Comment: thanks, so it is a typo as I thoguht.